# Intel threads C API

Tags: c++, c, tbb

We would like to use `Intel Threading Building Blocks` from plain C, not C++. Do they have also C API?

Comment: Have you looked at the pthreads library for C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Threaded Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) is a C++ API that makes heavy use of templates, constructors, destructors, and other C++ only features.   Intel does not provide a C version.  Given the C++ feature set used, I find it hard to imagine anyone else has tackled a port to pure C.

Comment: What about the solution to write a custom "home-grown" C wrapper of TBB?

Comment: @James, That's not a good idea. Is there any specific reason you should use TBB? Cilk Plus also supports very decent task parallelism with work-stealing scheduler. Although TBB provides wider parallel constructs, Cilk Plus may be a good choice for C.

Comment: @minjang: Good point, Cilk+ is also from Intel? Intel develops two similar framework for parallelism?

Comment: Cilk Plus (They don't write as Cilk+) is also from Intel. Yes, Intel compiler provides both Cilk Plus, TBB, and OpenMP. All of them can be used together. Cilk Plus supports parallelism via new keywords, while TBB supports by pure library-level implementation.

Answer (score 3):

It's specifically designed to address a perceived problem with C++.  I don't think it exists for any other languages.

Answer (score 2):

As Ashelly and jeffamaphone mentioned, TBB only supports C++ because most of the parallel constructors are based on C++ template and C++11 lambda.

However, if you still want to use a parallel library for pure C, you may try either OpenMP and [Cilk Plus](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-cilk-plus/). Note that OpenMP is represented as C/C++ `#pragma` and some C-style APIs. Cilk Plus is basically based on C++, however, it supports mostly important features in C as well.